# How to use Groovy 2.0 in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, groovy

I want to use `groovy 2.0 in Netbeans 7.1.2` because I want to use the static type checking.

By default that Netbeans uses the library Groovy 1.6.4 - groovy-all.jar

***How do I get Netbeans to use Groovy 2.0.***

I tried to just delete the groovy 1.6.4- groovy-all.jar library and add the groovy2.0-groovy-all.jar.

I tried to go to `tools -> libraries -> groovy 1.6.4` and replace the jar with the `groovy 2.0 jar` there.

Both result in the same error:

```
The includeAntRuntime=false option is not compatible with fork=false
/root/NetBeansProjects/myProject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:606: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/NetBeansProjects/myProject/nbproject/groovy-build.xml:23: Compilation Failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans 7.2 came out today, and that ups internal Groovy support to v1.8.6

I don't think you can just drop Groovy 2.0 into NetBeans and expect it to support it (so much has changed)

However, this doesn't stop you using your own Ant/Gradle (there's a work in progress [Gradle plugin here](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/more_serious_attempt_at_a)) build script and using this to manage your dependencies.  But NetBeans won't know anything about the type checking, so you will probably have to ignore some stuff that it says is an error (but which isn't)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `netbeans-7.2.1/groovy/modules/ext/groovy-all.jar` for the new one, but respecting the name `groovy-all.jar`, and the compilations will be done using groovy 2.

Test it executing :

```
println GroovySystem.getVersion()
```